# Three event probability

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a 3 events probability question.

> If there are 30 boys, 20 girls and 5 teachers, randomly choose 10 people. What is the probability of at least 1 person is teacher and 1 person is girls?

I got the answer,
$$
P(G\geq 1 \cap T \geq 1) =
1 - P(T=0 \cap G=0) = 0.998973
$$
It is correct? I believe there is still something, but I’m not sure.
Please guide, thank you!

Comment: $P(G\geq 1 \cap T \geq 1) = 1 - P(T=0 \cup G=0)$  not $1 - P(T=0 \cap G=0)$.  So your answer is not correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Tot=C(55,10)$

$P(G=0)=C(35,10)/Tot$

$P(T=0)=C(50,10)/Tot$

$P(T=0 \ \& \ G=0)=C(30,10)/Tot$

Don't forget to avoid overcounting.

So:
$P(G>=1\  \& \  T>=1)=1-[P(G=0)+P(T=0)-P(T=0 \ \& \ G=0)]$

Answer (score 1):

we should minus other events like
1 - P(10B, 0G, 0T) - P(9B, 0G, 1T) - P(8B, 0G, 2T) - P(7B, 0G, 3T) - P(6B, 0G,3T) and so on

Comment: Because the condition is at least one female and at least one teacher, that's mean we need to minus out one female and zero teacher, two female and zero teacher, three female and zero teachers and so on right? I minus out this event is because it didn't fulfill the requirements of at least one female and at least one teacher

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you calculated $P(0T,\,10B,\,0G)$ correctly, this is correct. It should be $$1-P(0T,\,10B,\,0G)=1-\frac{30\times29\times28\times\cdots\times21}{55\times54\times\dots\times46}$$